# Error while upload packaged applications to Submission in partner.microsoft.com

Tags: windows-10-universal

I have a UWP app and a WPF console app for special SDK (can't work in UWP). Linked these apps with default bridge (aka FullTrust). Then I package them with default package project for Windows apps.
But when I tried to upload my .msixupload file to Submission in Microsoft Store, I got this message:

> Package acceptance validation error: We encountered a fatal error while parsing the package: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source. Try again or upload a new package.
> [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDulk.jpg)

Apps works fine in release. But can't upload a store.

[This solution does not help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/321652/upload-desktop-bridge-app-to-microsoft-store-has-v.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.
In package project file .wapproj, delete PackageReference with Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools

```
<Project>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.19041.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```